# How to set Google Group so anyone on the web can send us an email?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-groups

I've been trying to find an option where I can set google group as a public so anyone on the web can send us an email. Apparently, this is what we have as an

[image]

Appreciate all the response.

Answer (score 0):

Set Groups for Business sharing options
Groups for Business sharing options determine if:

People outside your organization can view and participate in groups
Users in your organization can create their own groups
Group managers can add people outside your organization to groups
Note: If Groups for Business is ON, group members can always manage their own group memberships. Depending on the group's settings, they can add themselves to groups and opt in or out of receiving messages in email.
Set sharing options for Groups for Business
This feature requires turning on Google Groups for Business.

Your current account, vetterlukea@lexington1.net, doesn't have permission to do these steps. To continue, switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.
Switch to administrator account now or Learn more

From the Admin console Home page, go to Apps and then G Suite and then Groups for Business.
To see Apps, you might have to click More controls at the bottom.

Click Sharing settings or Advanced settings.
Select your preferences in the Sharing Options section. See below for details about each option.